# How can I hide deprecated operations in Swagger UI with the Swashbuckle.Core package?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

How can I hide deprecated operations in Swagger UI using the `Swashbuckle.Core` package?

Please note that I am not using the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package where the `Operations` collection is available on the `swaggerDoc` path instances in an
`IDocumentFilter` implementation. I am using the `Swashbuckle.Core` package (v 5.6.0) since I am working in a ASP.NET Web API project using .NET Framework 4.8.

I have written a couple of attempts and interacted with ChatGPT to no avail.

Here is the suggested method for the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package (again, I am not using this):

```
public class RemoveDeprecatedOperations : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        var pathsToRemove = new List<string>();

        foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
        {
            var operationsToRemove = new List<string>();

            foreach (var operation in path.Value.Operations)
            {
                if (operation.Value.Deprecated)
                {
                    operationsToRemove.Add(operation.Key);
                }
            }

            foreach (var operationToRemove in operationsToRemove)
            {
                path.Value.Operations.Remove(operationToRemove);
            }

            if (path.Value.Operations.Count == 0)
            {
                pathsToRemove.Add(path.Key);
            }
        }

        foreach (var pathToRemove in pathsToRemove)
        {
            swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(pathToRemove);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then register the RemoveDeprecatedOperations class with the Swagger generator in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My API");
                c.DocumentFilter<RemoveDeprecatedOperations>();
            })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                //…
            });
}
```

Is there anything equivalent for the `Swashbuckle.Core` package?